# Calculating a Positive Relative error

Tags: statistics

I need to graph the error between a set of observed
values and an expected values.

I calculate the relative error for each point as:

```
(observed - expect) / expected
```

This error however bounces up and down because the 
behaviour is sinusoidal. I want to make this error
always a positive quantity. Is there an error measure
like this? if so, what's its name?

I have looked for error measures, but all I find is
absolute and relative, and I am interested in a 
positive relative error.

Any help appreciated,
Ted.

Comment: you can always use the absolute value.

Comment: for example, if observed-expected < 0, then use expected-observed instead

Comment: Does this have a name?

Comment: @Ted Flethuseo: Yes, `absolute value`, as mentioned by picakhu. It's written $|x|$, defined by $$|x|=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x &\mbox{if $x\geq 0$}\\-x &\mbox{if $x\lt 0$.}\end{array}\right.$$ Most computers/spreadsheets can compute it, usually with the `abs` command.

Comment: absolute value..

Comment: You could multiply the result by its sign function ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function ) which will always make it positive ( this is identical to taking the absolute value ). Or just use the square root of the square, or , or.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is sensible to use the following error measure:

$$\frac{(O - E)^2}{E}$$

This is related to the test statistic for [Pearson's $\chi^2$ test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic).